# If I draw from the bag $n$ times, what's the probability that all stones are white?

Tags: probability

I've got a bag with $k$ stones in it, each either black or white with probability $\frac12$.  I draw a stone from the bag $n$ times; each time seeing that the stone is white, then tossing it back in the bag.

What is the probability that all $k$ stones are white, given $n$ draws of a white stone?

---

I *think* I understand specific cases, but I'm having trouble generalizing this.  For $k=3$ and $n=1$, you only see one stone, so the other two could be any ordered set of white and black, leaving a 1/4 chance of all three stones being white.

Using similar logic, I think that when $n=2$, you have a 1/3 chance of seeing only one stone and a 2/3 chance of seeing two different stones.  If you've seen one, odds are 1/4 that the other two are white, and if you've seen two, odds are 1/2 that the other one is white.  Together, the chance of all three being white is 5/12.

How can I generalize this for any $n$ and $k$?

Comment: What assumptions are made about the distribution of the actual number of whites in the bag? A natural one would be that there are $j$ whites in the bag woth probability $\binom{j}{k}2^k$. But one needs some info about that distribution to solve this problem, e.g. using Bayes' rule.

Comment: @Adriano The $k$ is the fixed number of stones in the bag. The random variable is the number, say $t$ of white stones in the bag. Then given $n$ draws with all results white, OP wants the probability that the random variable $t$ has the value $k$.

Comment: @coffeemath Ah I see. I guess I have trouble understanding how the actual number of white stones in the bag is a random variable. Shouldn't $t$ be a fixed constant?

Comment: @Joe: I have added the phrase "with probability $\frac12$", to make the question amenable to analysis. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @TonyK, that was indeed what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption that each stone in the bag is black or white with probability $\frac12$ means that the event $E_j$ for "there are $j$ white stones in the bag" has probability $\binom{k}{j}/2^k.$ Then using Bayes' rule, and cancelling out the common factor of $1/2^k$ everywhere, we find that the likelihood that the bag originally contained all white stones, given we drew with replacement $n$ times and always got white, is the reciprocal of the number
$$\sum_{j=0}^k (\frac jk)^n \binom{k}{j}.\tag{1}$$
Here the $k^n$ can be brought out of the sum, and the remaining sum can, for a specific $n ,$ be obtained by starting with the expansion of $(1+x)^k$ and repeatedly doing the steps "differentiate, then multiply by $x$" and putting in $x=1$.

Added explanation: Let $A$ be the event of drawing all whites in the $n$ draws with replacement from the bag of $k$ stones. The event where all stones in the bag are white, in the above notation, is $E_k$ with probability $\binom{k}{k}/2^k=1/2^k.$ Then the question is to find the conditional probability $P(E_k|A)$. This suggests using Bayes' theorem since the probabilities of the reversed conditionals $P(A|E_j)$ are easy to find, and are $(j/k)^n$ since we are drawing $n$ times with replacement from a bag containing a proportion of $j/k$ white stones. In Bayes' theorem the numerator will then be $P(A|E_k)\cdot P(E_k)=1\cdot (1/2^k)$, while the denominator will be, after cancelling the common factor $1/2^k$ from everything, the expression (1) above.

If we denote the conditional p[robability sought by $P(k,n)$ we can work things out for some small $n$ as $P(1,n)=1$, which seems clear, next
$$P(2,n)=\frac{2^n}{2^n+2},\\ P(3,n)=\frac{3^n}{3^n+3\cdot 2^n+3},
\\P(4,n)=\frac{4^n}{4^n+4\cdot 3^n+6\cdot 2^n+4}.$$
The pattern of binomial coefficients appearing here seems to continue as one finds $P(5,n),P(6,n),$ and so on.

Comment: In the added explanation, at one point you have (k k)/2^k.  Is it supposed to be two ks inside the binomial?

Comment: @Joe Yes, and $\binom{k}{k}=1$ is the number of ways that all $k$ of the $k$ stones in the bag can be white, which is then divided by $2^k$ to get the (unconditional) probability that originally all the balls in the bag were white.